# How to create a view with unknown structure content?

Tags: android, xml, view, rss

How to create a view (article page) based on the url given from rss xml?

More details:

1) I download xml (rss feed), get all items from it (article_url, preview_title, image_preview_url) and use them in listviewadapter to show some article preview info.

2) How should I create detailed article view consist of full article content given by article_url earlier? Some of articles has multiply images or images and text or looks like text-image-text-image-text, etc. How should a deal with it? (or how to get this unknown structure article content from article_url webpage?)

Could you give me an advice, please?

Comment: use some existing layouts like LinearLayout or extend ViewGroup to create a custom lsyout and then based of the content downloaded add some Views (TextView, ImageView) to that layout

Answer (score 0):

Add imageviews or textviews dynamically in your layout,like

```
ImageView imgv = new ImageView(context);
```

or Create a linear layout in your xml and create another separate example layout having all the imageviews and text views and add that layout as many times you will get from the xml in that parent xml linear layout.